# How to register and enqueue JavaScript files without breaking plugin dependencies?

Tags: theme-development, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

In theme development, what is the best way to register and enqueue JavaScript files to avoid problems with plugins?

I want to create a theme which uses scripts like jQuery, Masonry and so on. I downloaded the scripts and added them via the reqister and enqueue function to **avoid problems with Wordpress Updates**.

```
function my_scripts() {
  // Register scripts
  wp_register_script( 'my_masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); 
  // Add scripts before closing body tag.
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_masonry', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

**The other way** would be to use the built-in Wordpress scripts to may avoid problems with plug-ins.

```
function my_scripts() {
  // Add scripts before closing body tag.
  wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

What is the better approach?

Comment: **Always** use core-bundled scripts, rather than custom versions of those scripts. Core, Themes, and Plugins all rely on the assumption that the core-bundled version of a script will be registered and available to be enqueued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jquery-masonry included in Wordpress core:

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-masonry', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

If you really need the standalone masonry library, you should use your "first way" but I would not use "my_masonry" as handle for the script, I would use "masonry" if you have not modified the code. Also, use the correct version number of the library (I think your are not really using 1.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

function theme_name_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-
name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-
name', get_template_directory_uri
() . '/js/example.js', array(),
'1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',
'theme_name_scripts' );

add to tour function php.